# Dim each object vs. comma separated

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have a VBA script which controls Internet Explorer. However, with a recent browser update at my company, the script no longer works for everyone. The error occurs when I am trying to set the `HTMLDocument` like this:

```
Set htmlDoc = IE.Document
```

The issue seems to begin, when the objects are initalized (`Dim`). If I initialize with a `Dim` for each object, then the code will **not** work:

```
Dim oShellWin As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
Dim oWin As Object
Dim oWinTable As Object
Dim ieRunning As Boolean
Dim IE As Object
Dim sWindowTitle As String
Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 
Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
```

However, if I use a comma separated `Dim` instead, then suddenly it works again:

```
Dim oShellWin As SHDocVw.ShellWindows, _
    oWin As Object, _
    oWinTable As Object, _
    ieRunning As Boolean, _
    IE As Object, _
    sWindowTitle As String, _
    htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, _
    htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement, _
    htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
```

What is the difference between the two? From what I understand, they should do the exact same thing, but that is clearly not the case...

Comment: They both are the same. It shouldn't make a difference. I think the error is somewhere else

Comment: I can change between the two ways of `Dim` (and nothing else), and it will make the code either break or work. It is quite odd...

Comment: What is the error?  It worsks ok for me.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I dont have the excact error message, as it works on my PC as well. I do run a slightly different setup than the PCs it fails on though. This lead me to the conclussion, that it is probably related to a recent browser update.

Comment: i would suggest looking at `IE` on both machines.  Is it `nothing` or containing something, then `typename(IE)` on both machines.